# Why is this.Hide not working?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make an autoupdater for my program and basically it just opens my program while keeping the autoupdater open.

I tried changing the version and the code worked (closing and opening dl link).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using MaterialSkin;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;

namespace Sinips
{
    public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.Grey900, Primary.Grey800, Primary.Grey800, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient checkVer = new WebClient();
            string Version = checkVer.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/vSLsy7CF");
            if(Version != "1.0.0")
            {
                WebClient dl = new WebClient();
                string link = dl.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/ALTc67JZ");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link);
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            { 
                Form2 main = new Form2();
                this.Hide();
                main.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean `this.Hide` is not working ?

Comment: Yes. It works fine, and opens the program... but the autoupdater is not closing. this.Hide(); will refuse to work.

Comment: Hi @saltyturtle, nice first question. You might want to edit the title to mention `MaterialForm` specifically. And, read up on how to make your example a [mcve].

Comment: I suppose this isn't working, because the autoupdate window isn't visible _yet_ inside the load callback.

Comment: @PMF Do you think I should use Form1.Shown?

Comment: Yea, just needed to google that first, but I would try that. See here for the order of events: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: @PMF Just tried, does not work :(

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW Winforms is what I'm targetting

Comment: @saltyturtle Try `var main = new Form2(); this.HandleCreated += (s, e) => { this.Visible = false; };`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting visible to be false

```
 this.Visible=false;
 Form2 main = new Form2();
 main.Show();
```

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: It will not work in `Load` event.